# Can I configure XJC bindings to generate collections as Set instead of List

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

Given a schema such as this:

```
<xs:element name="Group" type="GroupType"/>

<xs:complexType name="GroupType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="OptionsType" name="Options" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element type="PageContainerType" name="PageContainer" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="PageContainerType">
    <xs:sequence>
      ...
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

XJC will generate Java something like:

```
public class GroupType {
  @XmlElement(name = "Options", required = true)
  protected OptionsType options;
  @XmlElement(name = "PageContainer")
  protected List<PageContainerType> pageContainer;
  ...
}
```

I want to enforce a unique collection for the PageContainer element. This is a reverse-engineering project so I'm not too concerned about making sure the schema enforces it explicitly.

Is it possible to generate the `PageContainer` element as a `Set<PageContainerType>`, by either specifying something in the schema or in XJC bindings?

Answer (score 1):

JAXB runtimes (atleast [Metro](http://jaxb.java.net/) and [MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)) can handle properties of type java.util.Set.  For an example see:

- [Mapping Java collections which contains super- and sub-types with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047998/mapping-java-collections-which-contains-super-and-sub-types-with-jaxb)

Both the Metro and MOXy JAXB implementations use the same XJC tool to compile XML schemas into Java classes.  You may want to post your question to the following forum:

- http://forums.java.net/jive/forum.jspa?forumID=46

You may also be able to achieve the desired result by writing an XJC plugin:

- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/06/writing_a_plugi.html